# JPA: how to make a field auto increment

Tags: jpa, mysql, eclipselink, auto-increment

I use Eclipselink as my JPA provider, how can I make a field auto increment?

Comment: Wouldn't you like to be implementation-independent?

Comment: Do you mean, set auto increment on the database side, instead of using JPA? make sense. It easy to set auto-increment on the database side

Comment: No I mean, you specifically mentioned Eclipselink. But JPA is an abstract interface and you're supposed to write against the JPA API. So I wondered why you specifically mentioned Eclipselink. Shouldn't this requirement also work when you're using Hibernate as JPA provider? You would normally like it to.

Comment: Can you clarify your exact need? Do you want an auto-increment field per entity or global to all entities?

Comment: @Pascal: Sorry, if I wasnt clear about my question. I just want an auto - increment that inside one entity, not too all entity. Although, that would be a interesting question, btw. @BalusC: Sorry, BalusC, I thought Hibernate and Eclipselink are two completely different things. I have no idea, the implementation on EclipseLink, will work in Hibernate. So is there a tremendous different between the 2 providers? Sorry for the late replies, I have limited internet access lately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just want an auto-increment field for 1 entity.

Yes, I get that, this is what you wrote in your question. But it can be interpreted in several ways and repeating the same thing without clarifying doesn't help much :)

> So does Pascal's way work or I have to do what Bytecode suggest, query select (max) counter + 1 from MyEntity, to get the next value, then set it to the design field, the persist?

If you want to increment a **field** per entity record (e.g. a "counter" for `Order` with id=1, another one for `Order` with id=2), what I suggested would work.

If you want a behavior similar to a primary key (i.e. an auto-incremented **column**), it won't. And in that case, standard JPA doesn't offer any particular facility (standard JPA only allows `GenereatedValue` on `Id` annotated field). The only way I can think of would be to insert another dedicated entity just to get the primary key from it.

---

Your exact requirement is unclear but I'm assuming you're talking about a random field, not the primary key. In that case, you could maybe use life cycle callbacks methods:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    ...
    private int counter;
    ...

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    protected void increment() {
         counter = counter + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess this ain't gonna work. For new entities persisted into the DB it always sets their counter field to 1, not `select max(counter) + 1 from MyEntityTbl`. Having said that the OP's question is not very clear...

Comment: @Bytecode You're right, this doesn't give you a `select max(counter) + 1`. But I don't know if this is what the OP wants exactly.

Comment: @Bytecode, Pascal: I just want an auto-increment field for 1 entity, and I end up setting it from the database side, instead of via JPA. However, I do want to learn how to set it via JPA. So does Pascal's way work or I have to do what Bytecode suggest, query `select (max) counter + 1 from MyEntity`, to get the next value, then set it to the design field, the persist?

Comment: @Harry I think that @Bytecode's comment was more an observation of the incorrectness than a solution. I don't see how you can implement a `select max(counter) + 1 from MyEntity` in a concurrent environment.

Comment: thank you. it make sense. I think this is what `bytecode` want to say as well, [quote from bytecode] `@Harry: unfortunately it looks like that EclipseLink cannot make non-ID fields auto-incremented`. Thank you

Comment: @Harry It's just not part of JPA.

Answer (score 2):

JPA 2.0 allows you to set auto_increment in a non-id field as long as you define the auto increment column in your schema - Hibernate / EclipseLink will not do it for you:

```
`non_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

and then in your entity:

```
 @Column(name = "non_id")
 @GeneratedValue
 public void setId(Long id) {
   this.id = id;
 }
```

will do the trick.

Comment: The `@GeneratedValue` annotation just do nothing in this case. The autoincrement works, of course, but after `persist` the field value is not automatically refreshed from DB, so it stays `null` until entity will be `refresh`ed.

Answer (score 1):

@Harry: unfortunately it looks like that EclipseLink cannot make non-ID fields auto-incremented. But looks like OpenJPA does have this feature:

[OpenJPA allows you to use the GeneratedValue annotation on any field, not just identity fields. Before using the IDENTITY generation strategy, however, read Section 3.4, “ Autoassign / Identity Strategy Caveats ” in the Reference Guide.](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/jpa_overview_meta_field.html#jpa_overview_meta_gen)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql (not sure if it works for other DBs) and make the column auto increment from DB side, following code should work

```
@Column(name = "counter", unique = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
@Generated(value = GenerationTime.INSERT)
private Long counter;
```

Answer (score -1):

Some JPA impls allow you to set GeneratedValue on the field whether it is PK or not

Comment: Which implementations?